# C# dynamic JObject not working after upgrading to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, dynamic, json.net

I wanted to start using dynamic in an old C# project so I set the target to framework to 4.0 and included the reference Microsoft.CSharp.

When I attempt to create a dynamic JObject and assign it a value, it gives me the exception:

> "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException:
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for
> 'test'

This is the line throwing the exception:

```
dynamic ree = new JObject();

ree.test = true;
```

In my C# xamarin project, it creates a JToken of type boolean with the value true and assigns it to `ree`.

Comment: So you upgraded from .NET 4.0 to which version?

Comment: @dbc I upgraded to 4.0 from 3.5

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by reinstalling the nuget package since it probably didn't implement this feature in the older version.